# Is it needed to convert pandas dataframe to numpy array to display the image and co-ordinates stored in it?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe which stores a couple of image urls and its annotation details(x,y co-ordinates,height and width).I want to display the image in python. Should I convert the dataframe to numpy array first (to eventually use matplotlib imshow to display the image).
Or is it possible to use matplotlib to pull data from dataframe to display the image? Which is easier?

Comment: There would be no difference either way

Comment: Thank you. I have a huge number of images and their co ordinates. So will it make any difference in using numpy array or dataframe terms of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.DataFrame({'image_url':['https://dcist.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/wilford_newsletter.jpg'], 'about':['a cat']})

# Use df.iloc[0] to pull the first image url, and requests to download the data for the image
a = plt.imread(requests.get(df.iloc[0]['image_url'], stream=True).raw, format='jpeg')

plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image from first url in dataframe shown in matplotlib plot]